# How to change SKSpriteNode size and colour in didBeginContact without SKTexture?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I have been changing SKSpriteNode colour and size within didBeginContact in the following way, using an SKTexture.

```
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == spriteCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory    {
     var newSprite = firstBody.node
     let newImage = SKTexture(imageNamed: "newSprite.png")
     (newSprite as? SKSpriteNode)?.size = newImage.size() //magic
     oldToNewSpriteAction = SKAction.setTexture(newImage)
     newSprite!.runAction(oldToNewSpriteAction)
 }
```

Now I am creating a sample code without SKTextures, setting my SKSpriteNodes in the following way:

```
oldSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: oldSpriteSize)
newSprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.BrownColor(), size: newSpriteSize)
```

How can I change the sprite colour and size within didBeginContact without SKTextures?

Comment: ... just do exaclty what you are doing, but instead of newImage.size(), you use whatever size you want, and then newSprite.color = UIColor.whateverColor()

Comment: @Knight0fDragon `newSprite =  firstBody.node`, making it an `SKNode`, so when I do `newSprite.color = UIColor.blueColor()` I get an error that says `Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'color'`. Also if I understand you well, there is no need to use `newImage`, right?

Comment: Because you need to cast it as an skspritenode

Comment: Downcast with `if let newSprite = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
newSprite.color = UIColor.redColor()
newSprite.size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 250)
```

Comment: and? with such size you will have huge sprites (much greater than 250x250)